Copy files with wildcard "*" in Kubernetes InitContainer
I am trying to copy all the files from an image to a volume. However, kubernetes seems to not interpret the wildcard correctly. So, when I use the following, it fails with "not found":
initContainers:
- name: init-container-name
  image: <image path>
  command:
  - cp
  - /foo/bar/*
  - /output

How can I get Kubernetes to interpret the * correctly? Is there a way to copy the contents without the surrounding bar folder?
I can copy the whole folder:
initContainers:
- name: init-container-name
  image: <image path>
  command:
  - cp
  - -r
  - /foo/bar
  - /output

But this results in an /output/bar when I just want the files themselves in output. I've also tried - "/foo/bar/*" and - "/foo/bar/"* but that doesn't work either.


How can I get Kubernetes to interpret the * correctly?

You don't, because Kubernetes doesn't know or care about shell wildcards in your command.
Wildcards are interpreted by your shell, and you're not running a shell command. You are passing the literal string /foo/bar/* to the cp command.
You need to wrap your command in a shell, like this:
initContainers:
- name: init-container-name
  image: <image path>
  command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - |
    cp /foo/bar/* /output

